# Group ActionEvents of buttons into a class

Tags: java

I have written a method to controll all buttons of a class:

```
public void buttonController(JButton buttonStimmeErfassen, JButton buttonProjekteLaden, JButton buttonDBimport, JButton buttonErfasserSpeichern, ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(buttonStimmeErfassen)) {
        new TabController().tabWechseln(1,e);
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(buttonProjekteLaden)){
        new TabController().tabWechseln(2,e);
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(buttonDBimport)){
        new TabController().tabWechseln(3,e);
    } else if(e.getSource().equals(buttonErfasserSpeichern)); {
        new StartTabModel().erfasserSpeichern(StartTab.textfeldErfasser,buttonErfasserSpeichern,e,frame);
    } 
}
```

The buttons are called in my view class:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        e.getActionCommand();
        new StartTabModel().buttonController(buttonStimmeErfassen, buttonProjekteLaden, buttonDBimport, buttonErfasserSpeichern, e);
    }
```

It works so far. But i have another method and if i fire any button this last method is always called too.

```
    public void erfasserSpeichern(JTextField j, JButton b, ActionEvent a, JInternalFrame frame) {

        if (j.isEditable() == true) {
        a.getActionCommand();
        j.setEditable(false);
        b.setText("Logout");

        if (j.getText().equals("S119")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "xxx");
            j.setEditable(true);
            b.setText("Login");
        } else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "xxx");

    } else if (j.isEditable() == false) {
        a.getActionCommand();
        j.setEditable(true);
        b.setText("Login");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "xxx");
        j.setText("S119");
    }
```

Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... Stupid mistake...
There was a semicolon in my else if:

```
else if(e.getSource().equals(buttonErfasserSpeichern));
```